# How to add object to unparameterized Java List?

Tags: java, scala, interop

I have a Java object `OldFashioned` that extends Java 1.4 `List`:

```
[Java] 
class OldFashioned extends List { ... }
```

That is, `OldFashioned` doesn't take any type parameters. I need to add `SomeObject` to it. In Java there's no problem, since it treats `List` 1.4 as `List<Object>` 1.5 and allows to add any subclasses of `Object` to the collection. But Scala doesn't. So next code doesn't work:

```
[Scala]
val oldFashioned = new OldFashioned()
oldFashioned.add(new SomeObject)       // found: SomeObject; required: E
```

That is, *Scala compiler* requires to pass type parameters to `OldFashioned` that actually doesn't take them:

```
[Scala]
var oldFashioned: OldFashioned[SomeObject] = null    // OldFashioned does not take type parameters
```

How can I overcome it and add `SomeObject` to `OldFashined`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I can't believe one of my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313948/use-case-and-examples-for-type-pattern-with-type-variable) finds a usage here (you should go upvote agilesteel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313948/use-case-and-examples-for-type-pattern-with-type-variable/7318089#7318089))

```
def add(oldFashioned: OldFashioned, any: Any): Boolean = oldFashioned match {
  case l: java.util.List[a] => l.add(any.asInstanceOf[a])
}

val oldFashioned = new OldFashioned
// oldFashioned: OldFashioned = []

add(oldFashioned, "test")
// res0: Boolean = true
add(oldFashioned, 1)
// res1: Boolean = true
add(oldFashioned, new Object)
// res2: Boolean = true

oldFashioned
// res3: OldFashioned = [test, 1, java.lang.Object@1db8f8e]
```

Edit: I guess as long as I'm going to cast:

```
oldFashioned.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[SomeObject]].add(new SomeObject)
```

Comment: Funnily, IDEA highlights `[a]` as an error, but Scala compiler doesn't complaint, so it works. Upvotes for both your and agilesteel's answers. Thanks!

Comment: I already started to wonder, why one of my old answers was getting a few upvotes all of a sudden ;) Thanks right back at you!